# CommonJS Require Mechanics

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion, module, commonjs

According to my textbook, the definition of the require function is this

```
require.cache = Object.create(null);

function require(name) {
    if (!(name in require.cache)) {
        let code = readFile(name);
        let module = {exports: {}};
        require.cache[name] = module;
        let wrapper = Function("require, exports, module", code);
        wrapper(require, module.exports, module);
    }
    return require.cache[name].exports;
}
```

Notes:

- `readFile(name)` is an arbitrary function that depends on whether I am using node.js or a particular browser.
- We set the cache to be an empty object
- This is what my textbook quoted about the code.

> To avoid loading the same module multiple times, require keeps a store
> (cache) of already loaded modules. When called, it first checks if the
> requested module has been loaded and, if not, loads it. This involves
> reading the module’s code, wrapping it in a function, and calling it.

What I do not understand:
How does the recursion work in this case. I am just really confused about the wrapper function.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine you had these extremely simple modules<sup>1</sup>:

```js
// In square.js
const square = function (n) {
  return n * n;
}

module .exports = square
```

and

```js
// In squareAll.js
const square = require ('./square')

const squareAll = function (ns) {
  return ns .map (n => square (n))
}

module .exports = squareAll
```

with this main module:

```js
const squareAll = require ('./squareAll')

console .log (squareAll ([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]))
```

On that outer `require ('./squareAll')`, when we get to the line

```js
let wrapper = Function("require, exports, module", code);
```

we [create a new Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Function) that looks something like this:

```js
const wrapper = function (require, exports, module) {
  const square = require ('./square')

  const squareAll = function (ns) {
    return ns .map (n => square (n))
  }

  module .exports = squareAll
}
```

We call this constructed function passing our `require` function, our `module` object and its `exports` property.  That will then recursively call `require` when its first line is called:

```js
const square = require ('./square')
```

and that will use the Function constructor again, invoke *that* function, and will return the `square` function, assigning it to the `square` variable.  Back in the outer call, we will use the `square` function to define `squareAll`, assign that to `module.exports`, and then we will return it with:

```js
return require.cache[name].exports;
```

Our `index.js` function now has a reference to `squareAll`, which has a reference to `square`.  And because of the caching, the next time we `require` one of them, we will return the already-loaded version.

It's a fairly elegant process.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>Yes, these can be written more simply with arrow function.  I do, but wanted to make this understandable to as many as possible.</sup>